# Unity 2d, Animations start distorting

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

I'm making my first game and I just finished adding animations for walking and jumping. Everything looked good at first but with time they started distorting, even rotating (Rotation is Frozen).
This is how the character looks in the beginning:

[image]

But after some time of walking and jumping:

[image: ![https://ibb.co/m0xmF8Y]().]

Did anyone have a similar error?
Can anyone Help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rotate pixel art sprites without the aesthetics getting ruined?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135091/how-can-i-rotate-pixel-art-sprites-without-the-aesthetics-getting-ruined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this bug before, the cause of it was because I didn't created a rotation constraint, just freeze rotation and you should be good to go.

Comment: The question says "Rotation is Frozen" already, so it's not clear to me how this solves the problem.

Comment: Then It 100% is the Rigidbody's Body Type then, try changing it to Kinematic. 
I think that your character physics are screwing your rotations, change it and see if it works.